# what is right way to sort in ascending in C++ when overloading comparative symbol "<"

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I want to sort a vector in which the element type is a class that defined by myself in the following code.

```
struct Node {
    int _x;
    int _y;
    int _h;
    Node(int x, int y, int h) : _x(x), _y(y), _h(h) {}
    bool operator<(const Node &p) const {
        return _h > p._h; // > or <
    }
};

vector<Node> v; //priority_queue<Node> p;
...//push some objects
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```

It's very strange that sometimes I use "return _h > p._h" in overloading function to get an ascending order, but sometimes it's descending. Maybe not in the vector, but in other date structure that using comparative function, e.g, priority_queue, map, and so on

Is there have any detailed documents to introduce the comparative function?

Solved. I think I have a bad memory.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

Comment: can you show an example where you "maybe sometimes" get a different order?

Comment: @tobi303 sorry, I forgot, but I'm sure I met the sort problem several times

Comment: it looks I made a stupid mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the
>   requirements of Compare) which **returns ​true if the first argument is
>   less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second**.

Using such a function `sort(v.begin(), v.end());` sorts ascending.

Comment: Thanks, but if the overloading function locates in the class as above shown, which argument is the first one?

Comment: @vinllen  `this->_h` is the left hand side(first). So you should change your return statement comparison.